# execute JS function on keystroke

Tags: javascript

I have created a function that when the use fills in the two inputs comm and hour it populated the result in another input called phone.

```
calculate = function()
{
    var comm = document.getElementById('comm').value;
    var hour = document.getElementById('hour').value; 
    document.getElementById('phone').value = Math.round(comm*hour*phone/60);
}
```

At the moment if you type in comm and hour and then you click outside the input it calculates the result in phone.

What I am trying to achieve is to calculate at the moment you type on any of the two fields.

I have tried to find something that can help me here, but with no luck. Any advice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look into [`onkeydown`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onkeydown). Something like the following code.

```
document.onkeydown = calculate = function()
{
    var comm = parseFloat(document.getElementById('comm').value);
    var hour = parseFloat(document.getElementById('hour').value); 
    document.getElementById('phone').value = Math.round(comm*hour*phone/60);
}
```

This will call that function whenever a key is pressed on the page.

Comment: @lStoilov Awesome! Consider accepting if you feel like it helped you so others can benefit also. Happy coding!!

Comment: Will accept in 10 min, due to some limitation of the website :)

Comment: @ISoilov Thanks! Happy coding!!

Answer (score 2):

As @CharlieFish answer Use `document.onkeydown` to call event on key down and use `parseFloat` to convert your values to float

```
document.onkeydown = calculate = function()
{
    //hope you have define phone value
    var comm = parseFloat(document.getElementById('comm').value);
    var hour = parseFloat(document.getElementById('hour').value); 
    document.getElementById('phone').value = Math.round(comm*hour*phone/60);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
document.body.onkeypress(function(){
   // invoke your function here calculator()
   // additional logic can we added here too.
})
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want it to start working immediately use a IIFE (immediately invoked function expression) and add an event listener for 'keyup' so it will fire once the value in the input field has been set:

```
(function(){
  document.getElementById('foo').addEventListener('keyup',function(){
  //add your logic here
  console.log('someone pressed a key!');
});
}());
```

...just remember to parseFloat the values in your example before you try to calculate, as when you get them from the element they will be `typeof string` ...

so `value = parseFloat(value);`

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is trigger calculate function at text change event, just try this

```
<input type="text" id="comm" onchange="calculate();"/>
<input type="text" id="hour" onchange="calculate();"/>
```